# whats the recommended way of adding the fields to a djangoform object?

Tags: django, djangoappengine

whats the recommended way of modifying/adding the fields in a djangoform object i was trying adding a new key to the dictionary `obj.base_fields['new_field']='value_of_newfield`' but as it turns out that it will be added as a string and not a `CharField`,that can be worked around but some where down my gut i have this feeling that its not the recommended way ..and i am not talking about `obj(intial={'new_field':'value_of_newfield'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add an instance of a form field:

```
from django import forms
obj.base_fields['name_of_field'] = forms.CharField()
```